# Strange behavior with G++ CAS

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   bool lock = false;
   lock = __sync_val_compare_and_swap( &lock, false, true );
   cout << lock << endl;
}
```

I expect the result to be displayed as 1 but the o/p is 0. Just calling `__sync_val_compare_and_swap( &lock, false, true );` (so the return value is not captured) and then displaying lock results in 1 being displayed.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the GCC doco:

> `bool __sync_bool_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval, ...)`
> `type __sync_val_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval, ...)`
>
> These builtins perform an atomic compare and swap. That is, if the current value of *ptr is oldval, then write newval into *ptr.
>
> The “bool” version returns true if the comparison is successful and newval was written. The “val” version returns the contents of *ptr before the operation.

Seems to me that 0 is the right value.  I think you are incorrectly assigning "...the contents of `*ptr` before the operation" to `lock`.

This should output sensible results:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   bool lock = false;
   bool oldvalue = __sync_val_compare_and_swap( &lock, false, true );
   cout << lock << ", " << oldvalue << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `lock` variable as both an argument to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` (a pointer to `lock` is passed) and a recipient for the return value of `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`. This doesn't seem to make much sense. Which value are you interested in? The one returned through the first argument? Or the one returned as the return value of `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`? Decide which one you need an act accordingly.

Right now it looks that the return value of `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` is stored in `lock` last. That value should be `0`, according to the specification of `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`. That's the value you are seeing in your experiment.